# What is the reason for using the mean instead a regression inside a decision tree?

Tags: cart

A common problem with decisions trees is that they don't generalize outside the range of the data, e.g. time series. For this reason, I want to code a regression version of the decision tree, that performs regression estimation instead of estimation with the mean. I haven´t seen this kind of implementation in ML packages, so I guess comes with statistical or computational issues.

What issues would I face in this coding journey? Can you point me towards resources on the topic?

Comment: So you would still like to build a tree, but inside each node of the tree you would use a linear model to make predictions, rather than just taking the mean value of all the units in the node?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: [Decision tree that fits a regression at leaf nodes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/439756/decision-tree-that-fits-a-regression-at-leaf-nodes)